# CLR 2.0 vs 4.0 performance?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, clr

Will a .NET program compiled for CLR 2.0 run faster if running unden CLR 4.0?

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Possibly if it hits one of the spots where the 4.0 runtime is better than the 2.0 runtime. But I don't know if there are many thus spots.

Comment: I don't doubt that, for some situations, it is faster. It's probably not the bottleneck in your application, if that's the direction your coming from.

Comment: Only one way to find out. Try it and see!

Answer (score 7):

Typically, no - it will be identical.

By default, the CLR 4 runtime will load the CLR 2 runtime to execute your CLR 2 code base.  Forcing execution under CLR 4 requires setting [`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx) in your app.Config.

If you add that flag, then it will run in v4 of the CLR.  In general, the performance is likely to be very similar, but it may differ slightly with the new runtime, due to changes in the JIT and core runtime.  There is no guarantee that CLR 4 will be faster - it may be slower at times, though in general, I would expect the performance to be very close under both runtimes.

If you're having performance issues, profile your application.  Changing the runtime will not fix a performance issue.  Profiling your application while running under both will be the only way to know if it makes a difference for you, however.

Comment: May I have a question about your answer, confusing me? _"The CLR 4 runtime will load the CLR 2 runtime to execute your CLR 2 code base."_ means that
if an application is built under the CLR 2.0 and its app.config has `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="false"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/></startup>`,
will the application be executed under the CLR 2.0 in spite of the app.config, having CLR 4.0?

Comment: @Reed - Per [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921976/#6963368) and MSDN documentation, `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` only applies to mixed-mode assemblies. The only settings that should matter for ordinary .Net apps with purely managed code are the `supportedRuntimes` tags, in order to force an older app to use a newer CLR.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, not noticeably. The runtimes are all backwards-compatible, and AFAIK libraries found in older versions were only modified if the language spec changed (for instance adding covariance/contravariance support) or it was identified as a real memory/CPU hog.

Answer (score 0):

Usually: **No**.

There are a couple of **corner cases** were performance improved, i.e. if the application floods the ThreadPool with small pieces of work then the **work-stealing ThreadPool** optimizations will be a big win.  This could also significantly change the order the work is performed, so some apps that accidentally rely on ordering could crash.

There are similar kinds of corner cases in the background **GC** (med-large object compacting) and Interop (object locking changes).

**Summary**

If the performance of a .NET 3.5 (CLR 2.x) app is worse than expected then try the app on .NET 4.5 (CLR 4.x).